# RSS Feed for All Tags with Excel

Tags: feature-request, feed

I would like a feed that includes every tag with the word "excel" in it.  So I would get excel, excel-2007, excel-2003, and a few others.  I have been subscribed to the excel tag, but I didn't realize there were other excel-related tags that I could be getting.

I can subscribe to each individually if that's the best way, but it does lead to duplicates and it's a heck of a lot of low volume feeds.

I can also combine the tags, but then when someone makes an excel-2010 tag, I'll have to know that it was made and update my feed settings.

I can accept that I might get tags that contain 'excel' that I don't want, but I can live with that.

Is there some existing way to accomplish this?  If not and you want to implement it, I suggest

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/~excel

where tilde+keyword would include all tags containing that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch it around:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel~

And you'll come to all questions where the tag starts with **[excel]**.

You'll see variants such as:

- excel
- excel-vba
- excel-2007
- excel-formula
- excel-2003
- excel-addins and so on and so forth and so how's your mother doing?

Click the RSS icon that will appear in your browser location bar. Or wherever it happens to crop up. There you will see a deluge of all the posts under that tag wildcard.

But because of the flood of excel prefixed tags, you might get a Bad Request - Error 400.

Just cut down some of those tags and spread your subscription across a couple of the feed variants. 10 tags per feed should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Add `excel*` as an interesting tag (or other similar wildcard such as `*excel*`.

Click on your new interesting tag.

Go to the bottom of the screen for an RSS Feed of everything that matches your new wildcard interesting tag.

---

Conversely you could just construct the url yourself:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=excel+or+excel-2003+or+excel-2005 (etc. etc. etc.)

or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel~

Comment: There's the smell of tacos and fajitas in the air.

Comment: @random: I don't see Rich B anywhere.

Comment: ... and we all celebrated his absence.